# Speeding query on json array with @>

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a configuration table where each line is holding a json array of {oid: "1.1.1" instance:"0" value: "abc"} elements.  I would like to run the following query that will return the oid, instance and value of specific elements.

```
SELECT c.*, d->>'oid' oid, d->>'instance'  instance, d->>'value' as value
FROM   configuration_bkp2 c , jsonb_array_elements(config->'data') d
WHERE  (d->>'oid'      = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'  AND    d->>'instance' = '0' ) OR   (d->>'oid'      = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.999.2.5.2'  AND    d->>'instance' = '0' )            
order by id
```

If I look for only one {oid instance} element and add the following 
part to the where clause it speeds things dramatically

```
"where (config->'data') @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}]' and ..."
```

However, if I do it for two elements

```
(config->'data') @> '[{"oid": "3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}, {"oid": "3.999.2.5.2", "instance": "0"}]' it runs much slower (60ms vs 4 seconds)
```

How can I speed my query for cases where I look for two or more `{oid instance}` elements?

Data sample:

```
{"_x": "312", "data": [{"oid": "3.10.2.5.35.3", "value": "0", "instance": "0"}, {"oid": "3.999.2.5.2", "value": "A", "instance": "0"}]}
{"_x": "483", "data": [{"oid": "3.10.2.5.35.3", "value": "2", "instance": "0"}, {"oid": "3.855.2.1.1", "value": "55", "instance": "0"}]}
{"_x": "486", "data": [{"oid": "3.10.2.5.35.3", "value": "3", "instance": "0"}, {"oid": "3.999.2.5.2", "value": "C", "instance": "0"}]}
{"_x": "489", "data": [{"oid": "3.10.2.5.35.5", "value": "3", "instance": "0"}, {"oid": "3.999.2.888.2", "value": "15", "instance": "0"}]}
```

```
CREATE TABLE configuration (
id serial PRIMARY KEY
, config jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE INDEX configuration_my_idx ON configuration
USING gin ((config->'data') jsonb_path_ops);
```

I'm using version 9.4 and the following are the two explain analyze for the queries

FAST - with only one oid

"Sort  (cost=116.34..116.39 rows=19 width=68) (actual time=17.700..17.701 rows=38 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: c.id"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 60kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.15..115.94 rows=19 width=68) (actual time=16.758..17.657 rows=38 loops=1)"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on configuration_bkp2 c  (cost=20.15..77.60 rows=19 width=36) (actual time=16.730..16.908 rows=38 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((config -> 'data'::text) @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}]'::jsonb)"
"              Heap Blocks: exact=14"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on configuration_my_idx  (cost=0.00..20.14 rows=19 width=0) (actual time=16.706..16.706 rows=38 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((config -> 'data'::text) @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}]'::jsonb)"
"        ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements d  (cost=0.01..2.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.018 rows=1 loops=38)"
"              Filter: (((value ->> 'oid'::text) = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'::text) AND ((value ->> 'instance'::text) = '0'::text))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 15"
"Planning time: 13.379 ms"
"Execution time: 17.825 ms"

Slow - with two oids

"Sort  (cost=76402.89..76426.46 rows=9428 width=68) (actual time=4772.034..4772.035 rows=76 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: c.id"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 97kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..75780.51 rows=9428 width=68) (actual time=12.621..4771.960 rows=76 loops=1)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on configuration_bkp2 c  (cost=0.00..361.90 rows=18790 width=36) (actual time=0.008..3.306 rows=18790 loops=1)"
"        ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements d  (cost=0.01..4.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.251..0.251 rows=0 loops=18790)"
"              Filter: (((value ->> 'instance'::text) = '0'::text) AND (((value ->> 'oid'::text) = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'::text) OR ((value ->> 'oid'::text) = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.999.2.5.2'::text)) AND ((((c.config -> 'data'::text) @> '[{"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3", "instance": "0"}, {"oid": "1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.999.2.5.2", "instance": "0"}]'::jsonb) AND ((value ->> 'oid'::text) = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.10.2.5.35.3'::text)) OR ((value ->> 'oid'::text) = '1.3.6.1.4.1.7352.3.999.2.5.2'::text)))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 444"
"Planning time: 0.225 ms"
"Execution time: 4772.250 ms"

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL do you use and could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com ?

Comment: Thank for the comment.  I added the EXPLAIN ANALYZE to my post

Comment: Please use explain.depesz.com for posting the query plan, to make it readable.